# Expect a jest test to resolve, but don't care about the value

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, jestjs

Let's say I have the following fn that I want to test:

```
const foo = async () => {}
```

This resolves of course, but how do I test that with Jest?

```
it('resolves', async () => {
  expect(await foo()).???
});
```

All of the examples I can find require values, e.g. `expect(await foo()).resolves.toBe(42)`

Comment: What are you trying to test (what is meant to be inside the function)?

Comment: I'm wrapping legacy code that either returns nothing or throws.  I really just care that the promise was resolved and don't care about the value

Comment: Yeah but to confirm whether promise resolves to correct value or not you have to test the value.. so if you test the value, you are also testing whether promise resolves or not

Comment: You shouldn't even need an `expect`. If `foo` throws the test will fail

Comment: I don't like having tests that only test for failures though ;)

Comment: You could be explicit by wrapping it with a `try/catch` and calling `done.fail()`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Update, by a two years wiser version of me

The property `.resolves` of an expectation object created by `expect()` is also an expectation object that has the same properties (the matchers) as a regular expectation object. The only difference is that it expects the actual value to be a `Promise` and the matchers apply to the resolved value, not to the promise.

If the promise returned by the function resolves it means that it does not throw (if it throws then it is rejected, not resolved).
Let's express this expectation in Jest code:

```js
it('resolves', async () => {
    await expect(foo()).resolves.not.toThrow();
});
```

### What is wrong with your code

You have tried:

```
expect(await foo()).resolves.toBe(42)
```

It doesn't work this way because the result of `await foo()` is not a `Promise` but the resolved value of the `Promise` returned by `foo()` (assuming it resolves).
`.resolves.toBe()` expects a `Promise`, Jest complains and the test fails.

When `await` is in front of the `expect()`, `foo()` returns a `Promise`, `expect()` wraps it into a object whose `.resolves.toBe...()` returns another `Promise` and `await` awaits for it.

The general rule is: if you put `await` inside the call to `expect()` then you cannot use `.resolves` or `.rejects` because the value that `expect()` receives is not a `Promise`.
In order to use `.resolves` or `.rejects`, the `await` keyword should stay in front of the `expect()` call.
Alternatively you can `return` the `Promise` instead of `await`-ing for it.

Read more about [`.resolves` and `.rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#resolves-rejects).

### Older answer

If you know that `foo()` always resolves to a value then you can use `.toBeDefined()`:

```
it('resolves', async () => {
  await expect(foo()).resolves.toBeDefined();
});
```

This doesn't work if `foo()` completes using `return undefined` or `return` (without a value) or it doesn't use `return` at all.

In this case you cannot use `.resolves` but you can simply return the `Promise` returned by `foo()` and Jest takes care of the rest:

```
it('resolves', () => {
  return foo();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't actually completely clear.  This is legacy code that actually does sometimes return, but the return value is irrelevant and all we care about is that it doesn't throw (e.g. `saveData()` might return the dataset for usability, but we actually only care that it's not throwing).  Trying to wrap an entire library that's out of our control so we don't have much flexibility.  I really am looking for a way to test that it resolves at all, and it's looking like the `try/catch` may be my best option.

Comment: I completely rewritten the answer. It should help you now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think jest natively supports this. However, the [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toresolve) library (community managed extensions) does with `#toResolve()`

```js
await expect(foo()).toResolve()
```

Jest devs [discuss the request here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5248) and refer us to `jest-extended`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just not use expect here:

```
it('resolves', async () => {
  await foo();
});
```

Should foo throw, it makes the test fail anyways. The output is a little bit different on failure, but very readable and understandable, too.

I prefer this way, as imo it is short and clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, and the ugly workaround I found was to assert *negatively* on a value I know wasn't ever going to be resolved, such as

```
await expect(somePromise).resolves.not.toBe({});
```

This works since `toBe` uses strict equality, and a newly created empty object is not strictly equal to any other object, meaning this assertion will pass as long as `somePromise` resolves with *anything*.

At first I intended to use a unique symbol, but `{}` works just as well.